# video background only in a part of body

Tags: html, css

I know that can use css to create a full-screen video background

but how can I only show the video background in one part?

for example, I create a 800*600 box in  part

how to make the background of this part to be video background, the remaining part still a image background?

Here is my css part code

```
nav{
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 5px solid black;
     margin: 0;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

video#bgvid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

and the html code

```
<nav>
  <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://courses.cs.cityu.edu.hk/cs2204/wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://courses.cs.cityu.edu.hk/cs2204/wildlife.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please share your current code

Answer (score 0):

You can give each DIV its own background, image, video or just a color. So you can simply place DIVs on top of each other (smaller elements covering only parts of larger elements), using absolute or fixed positions and z-indexes for their placement.

Your code only contains one element, so it's not possible to demonstrate it with that code. You'd need to post some more and give more detailed infos about what should be where.